# Using less than 10 LEDs on LM3914

Tags: led, integrated-circuit

The LM3914 IC has a divider that works over 10 LEDs.

Does this IC enable using less than 10 leds and does it automatically adjust the scale based on the number of LEDs (eg 5)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this IC enable using less than 10 LEDs

Yes.

> ... and does it automatically adjust the scale based on the number of LEDs (eg 5)?

No. How would it know?

To do this you would set the reference voltage input to be double the input voltage required for five LEDs.

For example if you connect the internal 1.25 V reference voltage REF OUT to R HI then you need to attenuate your input signal to 1.25 V / 2 = 0.625 V to get five LEDs. Usually a simple resistor divider will do the trick.

Comment: Loosely related question: does Rhi needs to be 1.5V less than V+ right? Can it be much less as long as its above 0 or does it need to be exactly 1.5V under V+?

Answer (score 1):

If using five LEDs you could connect the LED's cathode to two output pins and it will work well in both bar graph and moving dot modes.

If using five (plus or minus) LEDs in bar graph mode, there is no real difference.  Your choice is to use the first five outputs or last five outputs and adjsut the reference voltage.  I would use the first five outputs.

In moving dot mode you may want to make sure that at least one LED will always be on.  I would use the last outputs.